# ClamAV Freshclam won't update and there is no freshclam.log file?

Tags: debian, clamav

If I run `sudo freshclam` I get this error:

```
ERROR: Can't open /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log in append mode (check permissions!).
ERROR: Problem with internal logger (UpdateLogFile = /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log).
```

I went to `/var/log/clamav` to check it's permissions, but there isn't a clamav directory there. I tried `sudo locate freshclam.log` but nothing came back.

I'm running Debian 8 Jessie and ClamAV 0.99.2. I installed ClamAV using `sudo apt-get install clamav`. Clamscan works fine,

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the same process is already running automatically stop it with the command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/clamav-freshclam stop
```

and try again to manually with the command:

```
sudo freshclam
```

Comment: Hi, gave that a try and got the same error message?